# What should to be done to increase the text size in properties menu?

Tags: windows, text-size

[image: Source]
[image: Source]

I want to increase the text size of the texts pointed in the green bracket. But Windows allow title bar size, menu bar size, palette title, message boxes, tool tips, etc but there is no option for these texts. What can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of anyone needing to do this before. What is it for? My only thought would be to use a magnifier on part of the screen. It's not much of a solution but its the only way I know and would kind of work in a pickle.